# How to develop a desktop application that can be launched from a right-click on the finder

Tags: macos, desktop

I would like to create an application that meets the following requirements.

1. Ability to launch the applications from right-click on the finder. (like google drive)
2. Ability to edit files in the local environment from the application. (e.g., file renaming from the app)

[google drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWDCT.png)

However, I am not familiar with desktop app development and don't know what words to search for to get a hint.

Could you tell me terms, languages and frameworks as hint for this development?

I need terms, languages and frameworks to help me develop the above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.